# how to use Multiple Mysql Databases with a SINGLE PDO connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a webpage that has to use multiple databases at a time. In localhost, it works perfectly fine but while hosting in online free hosting sites, I get error if I use more than one PDO connection and only the first database connection works. Is there any possible way to use multiple databases using a single PDO connection?

Please HELP!

Comment: Show an simple example of what works (or doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a host, you don't have to specify a database:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1','USER','PASS');
```

Just make sure to include the database name when running your queries as such:

```
select * from db1.table1
select * from db2.table2
```

Comment: Tell me, please: let's say, the db name is included in PDO creation statement. Would it be the name of the default db in a connection on more dbs, or the name of the only accessible db through the PDO object? Thanks

Comment: If the name of the database is specified in the connection statement, as long as the other databases you are trying to access are accessible from the same host with the samer username/pass you can just specify the other databases on your subsequent queries.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad that worked! Don't forget to select best answer to allow others to try these steps first when they run into a similar issue!